# How to handle big numbers?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a very large number, assume some transaction id or big money involved. So, how I will handle the calculation on these ( add, multiple etc).  Does any other was to store it in the generic storage type( long, long long etc) to take care of such situation? Does boost support the solution?

Comment: Warning: money is a concept in itself, with specific patterns like `money bag` and use of integers instead of floating point numbers. See: http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/quantity.html

Comment: A simple `int64_t` will be able to store balances of roughly 9 trillions of currency, including cents (those are "real" trillions, not the US ones, multiply by 1000 for US trillions). Do you need to handle amounts of money that are several hundred times the amount of the total estate of large industry nations?

Comment: @Damon: That assumes the currency is something "sensible", like Euros, US Dollar, etc. Not Zimbabwe dollars, that you need 2,000,000.00 of to buy a loaf of bread.

Comment: @MatsPetersson use FP for those markets - the rounding errors are in any case swamped by the inflation while the operation is ongoing:)

Comment: @MartinJames: That phrase is funny, sad, insightful, disrespectful and true, all in one.

Comment: @MartinJames: Or, just forget about multiplying by 100 for cents and instead divide by 1,000 (or another big number, say 1M). If a currency has but meaningless digits, you can as well skip these. If a loaf of bread costs 2 million, you probably don't need to be any more precise than 100k. Of course there'll be small rounding errors if you calculate an interest or such, but in this case, who cares. As you said, the difference, if practical at all, will be eaten up by inflation anyway, and nobody would invest (i.e. "collect interest") in that currency either.

Answer (score 8):

You use a library that handles big numbers, like [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](http://gmplib.org/) which seems to be the most common. Or if you want Boost specifically, there's always [the Multiprecision library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html) (which can use GMP as backend).

Answer (score 5):

Please check boost multiprecision library .. It will be handy if your project is already using boost.
[boost multiprecision library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html)

Answer (score 2):

The closest to a standard is [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](http://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 0):

you can Wrote a large number of classes handle the calculation.
use the Array of characters store your data.

Comment: Actually, you would probably use an array of `uint32_t` and convert those to `uint64_t` when performing operations to handle overflow on those individual blocks (unless you have `uint128_t` available).

Answer (score -1):

If your numbers are larger than int, long or double. Use type long long and do not worry about adding, multiplication etc.

- long long largenum = 100000000000LL

Answer (score -1):

For This Question We Should Create a
Divided And Conquer Recursive Function And I Show You
How You can Do That :

Problem = Multiple U*V  Tow 100 Digit numbers .. 
Function Output = (Prod)  Return U*V
Long Long Long Integer Numbers ...
Like 9999999999999999*99999999999999999

Create Class Like That in your Programming Language ..

Long.Integer Prod(large.integer u , large.integer v)
{
large.integer x,y,w,z;
int m,n;
n = max("Digits of Number" u  , "Digits Of Number" v)
if(u == 0 || v == 0)
{
return 0;
}
else if (n 
{
return (u*v);
}else
{
m= n/2; // n = Digits Of Number u 
x= u div (10^m);
y= u  rem (10^m);
w = v div (10^m);
z= v rem (10^m);
return prod(x,w) * (10^ (2*m)) + prod(x,z) + prod(w,y) * (10^m) + prod(y,z);
}
}
}

In This Project t(n) = 4t(n/2) + CN !!

Sample For Tow Little Number In Mathematica :
4795 * 2412 = ?
n =4 (Digits of 4795)

Result :

(47 * 10^2 +95) * (24 * 10^2 + 12) => 
=> (47 * 24 * 10^4) + (47 * 12 * 10^2)+ (95 * 24 * 10^2) + 95 *12
=> 47 *24 * 10^4  + 47*12 + 95 * 24 + 10^2 + 95 * 12 = Result Of Function

**Best Regards Aj.Duende (Persian Guy)**