# Calculate exact value of exponentiation a^n

Tags: c++, algorithm, precision

For example, the result of `95.123^12` will be `548815620517731830194541.899025343415715973535967221869852721`.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
   double a = std::pow(95.123,12.0);
   std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10+2)<< a;
   return 0;
}
```

which give this result

```
548815620517732158537728.00000000000000000
```

How can I get the exact value?

Comment: You'll need to find a library that lets you do arbitrary-precision arithmetic.

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458424/how-to-handle-big-numbers

Comment: See also [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). You can't get 60 significant digits out of 53 bits.