# Find total number of 1s

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

Given a number `N`, find the total number of 1s present in `pow(11, N)` where `1 < N < 1000,000`. Solving this using a basic approach will land us into overflow issues since `N` could be very large. What are some ways that we can solve this efficiently?

Comment: @user1990169: but with 1M, it's going to be too slow.

Comment: You can try [GMP](https://gmplib.org/), or any equivalent library for your environment.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yes 11^1000000 will indeed be slow

Comment: @user1990169 And if the OP was interested in a different programming language it would be in the tags.

Comment: @Shubham.Shukla You should choose one of c or c++, the solutions will be very different, and please post any attempts you have made so far, or I am afraid the question will be closed soon.

Comment: Look at this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458424/how-to-handle-big-numbers

Comment: What sort of "1"? Do you mean that the number will be in base 2 or base 10?  e.g. the decimal value 11 contains two 1s in decimal but three 1s in binary (1011).

Comment: Looks like a test or a homework, but I do not see any effort from you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is the upper limit for N (1000,000 in the question) one thousand or one million?

Answer (score 2):

See [Calculate count of ones in result of 11^n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251011/calculate-count-of-ones-in-result-of-11n)

Multiplication by 11 is equal to multiplication by 10 (i.e. putting a 0 to the right of your number) and adding the original number. Using this you can work with strings, and you don't need an additional library.

Comment: (1) If you think it's a dupe, flag it, don't just rephrase the dupe answer. (2) This solution is taking O(n^2) time and is extremely inefficient (recall OPs numbers are up to 1,000,000. squaring it will give a huge number). Using a library can achieve significant improvement by using exponent by squaring.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is done in `dc`, the desk calculator.  Have a look at the bignum implementation there, or just use your favourite bignum library (e.g. [`libgmp`](https://gmplib.org/), the GNU arbitrary precision arithmetic library).

Make sure you have enough storage and CPU grunt.  Observe how memory use and processor time increase more rapidly beyond 11^100,000:

```sh
$ /usr/bin/time /tmp/countones 1000
105
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 166%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 760maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+896minor)pagefaults 0swaps

$ /usr/bin/time /tmp/countones 10000
1005
0.03user 0.00system 0:00.03elapsed 102%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 756maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+906minor)pagefaults 0swaps

$ /usr/bin/time /tmp/countones 100000
10190
1.12user 0.00system 0:01.12elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1144maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1041minor)pagefaults 0swaps

$ /usr/bin/time /tmp/countones 1000000
104499
44.52user 0.01system 0:44.54elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5280maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+3992minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

My quick script here is

```sh
dc -e "11 $1^p" | tr -d -c '1' | wc -c
```